# logon trigger to send an email

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I want to create a simple login trigger. 
basically if user = test , then send an email to me.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ServerLogon
ON ALL SERVER  WITH EXECUTE AS 'test'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'test' 
    -- send email to me
    ROLLBACK
END
```

But I cannot execute as 'test'

it says the user does not exists or you do not have pemission
but even when I use my username or make test as a sysadmin / db owner it still says the same thing

thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to use `EXECUTE AS` at all here?